# Cannot deploy asp.net openid library on shared hosting service

Tags: asp.net

I have deployed successfully the dotnetopenid dll under IIS7 but on my shared hosting service it says:

> Compilation Error Description: An
>   error occurred during the compilation
>   of a resource required to service this
>   request. Please review the following
>   specific error details and modify your
>   source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The
>   type or namespace name 'DotNetOpenId'
>   could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Why ?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, expand the project's references and check the properties of the DotNetOpenId reference. Specifically, make sure you have set it to "Copy Local", which will place a copy in the bin directory for you to upload to your shared hosting.